# NGINX Proxy Server pass "accept" header from request

Tags: http, nginx, header, http-headers, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using NGINX as a proxy cache server for my image optimization, and want to pass the `accept` HTTP header from the client's request to the backend through the proxy.
Is this possible and if so, how can I do this?

The reason why I want to do this is that because the backend decides based on the `accept` header the file format of the response.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: By default, all request headers are passed through an Nginx reverse proxy, although the `Host` and `Connection` headers [may be modified](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header).

Comment: I'm also using the `proxy_cache`. Could this cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

> [proxy_pass_request_headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_request_headers) on;

in your proxy settings block